# Meaning of 'I could be imagining that'

Tags: meaning-in-context

He looks like he could use a kiss, **but I could be imagining that**.

Is it means it's just my imagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I could be imagining**  means that it could potentially be my imagination.

Here imagining is a verb (a doing word) for example **I am imagining sitting on a beach**.

On the other hand, imagination is a noun.
For example **you have a wonderful imagination.**